# Can .env file make environment variables?

Tags: docker-compose

I tried to use a .env file to make environment variable, but it doesn't work.

These are my steps:

```
version "3"
services: 
  web:
    image: php-fpm:5.6.30
    env_file:
      - .env
```

This is .env file

```
TEST_ENV="HELLO WORLD"
```

It doesn't work when I start the container:

```
var_dump(getenv("TEST_ENV")); // output NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it seems to work. Maybe this can help you:

```
├── docker-compose.yaml
├── .env
└── myphp
    ├── Dockerfile
    └── script.php
```

My .env file

```
TEST_ENV="HELLO WORLD"
```

My `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: ./myphp
    env_file: .env
```

So my `docker-compose.yaml` will build the image myphp. The dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM php:5.6.30-fpm
COPY script.php /var/script.php
```

My `script.php`

```
<?php
var_dump(getenv('TEST_ENV'));

exit;
```

Than I perform `docker-compose up -d --build`. This will build my image and add the php script in it and it will run a container instance of that image.

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
15f0289bfbe8        test_web            "docker-php-entryp..."   3 seconds ago       Up 1 second         9000/tcp            test_web_1
```

I'm accessing my container

```
$ docker exec -it 15f0289bfbe8 bash
```

And I'm going the the `/var` folder where I've put my script (check dockerfile) and I'm exexcuting it + also just printing env var:

```
root@15f0289bfbe8:/var/www/html# cd /var/
root@15f0289bfbe8:/var# ls
backups  cache  lib  local  lock  log  mail  opt  run  script.php  spool  tmp  www
root@15f0289bfbe8:/var# php -f script.php
string(13) ""HELLO WORLD""
root@15f0289bfbe8:/var# echo $TEST_ENV
"HELLO WORLD"
root@15f0289bfbe8:/var#
```